# What exactly inset does in angular material mat-divider?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

One of the `mat-divider` attributes in Angular Material is `inset` an Input that takes a boolean. In the documentation, it refers to it as follows:

[image]

***Whether the divider is an inset divider.***

But it does not define it properly, so I wondered what it precisely does if we set it to `true.`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## mat-divider inset attribute

As you know, it is an `@Input()` of the `mat-divider` component that takes a boolean as a value. Mat divider draws a line (it can be horizontally or vertically with `vertical` @Input), and if we set the inset to `true`, all it does is to **try and wrap the line with the elements beside it**.

If you inspect the elements, you do realize that two properties may be applied to the element:

- **position: static**
- **margin: 80px** (it could be applied on the left, right, or both)

In the two following images, you can find out how setting `inset` to `true` or `false` differs from each other.

[image]

As you can see, in the left image, the mat-divider has a position of `static`, but on the other hand, on the right image, there are no spaces between the line and the edges of the component (here a mat-card component)

---

### Let's check another good example together regarding `inset` functionality:

[image]

As it is clear, there is a space on the left side of the divider (margin-left: '80px').

### I have provided some codes in StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2zuw4v?file=src/app/card-footer-example.html), which you can check more.

Comment: your stackblitz is not showing the static card version. how do you get it to have some spaces on the side when not in a card? For example if you have a divider in a menu list?